# Show only Distinct Values in an Access Report

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am writing an Access report showing a list of products on the left hand side and then month by month a shipped total. So something like this:

```
Product     Jan     Feb    Mar

xxx          10      11     12
```

My problem is that the product is pulled from a query however the values for each month are listed individually in the results.  Like this

```
Product     Quantity   Delivery Month

xxx               10              Jan

xxx               11              Feb
```

The problem I am having is that the report lists each instance of xxx instead of only listing it once.

Comment: I understand that but I do not think the problem is with the query the query pulls all the data I need the issue is that because each month is a distinct value the query lists each product 7 times (1 for each month from january through july). In the report I need a way to set the textbox to only show each product once.

Answer (score -1):

Making an assumption on your data layout, you'll probably end up with something like this:

```
TRANSFORM Sum(Table1.[Qty]) AS SumOfQty
SELECT Table1.[Product], Sum(Table1.[Qty]) AS [Total Of Qty]
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Table1.[Product]
PIVOT Format([Mth],"mmm") In ("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec");
```

My test table (which I named **Table1**) had 3 columns; **Product, Qty and Mth**.  Just substitute your field names accordingly.

In my case "Mth" was an actual date and not an abbreviation, which is why I had to reformat it.